# React-Native AzureAD: Not able to login with MS live accounts(ex. gmail account)

Tags: azure, react-native

I just implemented with my existing app, every thing is working as expected. But when i login with live account like gmail(xyz@gmail.com) or any external user of AD, it is not allowing to process further redirecting to the login screen.

Observation: When i login again with other live account it is showing as "you were already login with xyz@gmail.com you what to login with other account". It seems the user is logged successfully in the first attempt but internally redirections or code granting is not happening(my assumption).

implemented with react-native-azure-ad https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-azure-ad

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide some screenshot of error or error messages?

Comment: No i didn't get any error or error message it is simply redirecting to the MS login page, and when i try to login with another live account it saying "you were already login with firstattempt@gmail.com you want to login with other account". Even i am not getting any error in browser de-bugging.